# Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException, Unfortunately app has stopped

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-mapview, android-parser

Fetching JSON data into mapview, still I am getting map, but without Map Locations, which I have given in JSON File, and whenever I run my app getting this-Unfortunately app has stopped and Logcat says:-

```
 10-27 13:02:18.573: E/AndroidRuntime(719): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 10-27 13:02:18.573: E/AndroidRuntime(719):     at com.erachnida.restaurant.versionoct.MapView.onCreate(MapView.java:52)
```

please see the below code:-

```
public class MapView extends MapActivity {
public GeoPoint point;
TapControlledMapView mapView; // use the custom TapControlledMapView
List<Overlay> mapOverlays;
Drawable drawable;
SimpleItemizedOverlay itemizedOverlay;
JSONObject json = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
    drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    itemizedOverlay = new SimpleItemizedOverlay(drawable, mapView);
    itemizedOverlay.setShowClose(false);
    itemizedOverlay.setShowDisclosure(true);
    itemizedOverlay.setSnapToCenter(false);
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {



        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            // Perform a GET request for a JSON list
            HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(
                    "https://dl.***.com/maps.json");
            // Get the response that sends back
            HttpResponse response = null;
            try {
                response = client.execute(request);
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            // Convert this response into a readable string
            String jsonString = null;
            try {
                jsonString = StreamUtils.convertToString(response
                        .getEntity().getContent());
            } catch (IllegalStateException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            // Create a JSON object that we can use from the String
            JSONObject json = null;
            try {
                json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);


            try {

                JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray("maps");
                Log.e("log_tag", "Opening JSON Array ");
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String latitude = jsonObject.getString("latitude");
                    String longitude = jsonObject.getString("longitude");
                    String title = jsonObject.getString("title");
                    String country = jsonObject.getString("country");
                    double lat = Double.parseDouble(latitude);
                    double lng = Double.parseDouble(longitude);
                    Log.e("log_tag", "ADDING GEOPOINT" + title);
                    point = new GeoPoint((int) (lat * 1E6),
                            (int) (lng * 1E6));
                    OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(point, title,
                            country);
                    itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayItem);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
            }

            itemizedOverlay.populateNow();

            mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);
            if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                MapController controller = mapView.getController();
                controller.setCenter(point);
                controller.setZoom(7);
            } else {
                // example restoring focused state of overlays
                int focused;
                focused = savedInstanceState.getInt("focused_1", -1);
                if (focused >= 0) {
                    itemizedOverlay.setFocus(itemizedOverlay
                            .getItem(focused));
                }
            }

        }

    }.execute();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `AsyncTask` executes everything in `doInBackground()` inside of another thread, which does not have access to the GUI where your views are.

`preExecute()` and `postExecute()` offer you access to GUI before and after the heavy lifting occurs in this new thread, you can even pass the result of the long operation to `postExecute()` to then show any results of processing.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13043001/need-more-understanding-of-asynctask-in-android/13043121#13043121) see my answer.

Try with following its not perfect but give you idea.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
    drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    itemizedOverlay = new SimpleItemizedOverlay(drawable, mapView);
    itemizedOverlay.setShowClose(false);
    itemizedOverlay.setShowDisclosure(true);
    itemizedOverlay.setSnapToCenter(false);
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {



        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            // Perform a GET request for a JSON list
            HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(
                    "https://dl.***.com/maps.json");
            // Get the response that sends back
            HttpResponse response = null;
            try {
                response = client.execute(request);
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            // Convert this response into a readable string
            String jsonString = null;
            try {
                jsonString = StreamUtils.convertToString(response
                        .getEntity().getContent());
            } catch (IllegalStateException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            // Create a JSON object that we can use from the String
            JSONObject json = null;
            try {
                json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);


            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray("maps");
                Log.e("log_tag", "Opening JSON Array ");
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String latitude = jsonObject.getString("latitude");
                    String longitude = jsonObject.getString("longitude");
                    String title = jsonObject.getString("title");
                    String country = jsonObject.getString("country");
                    double lat = Double.parseDouble(latitude);
                    double lng = Double.parseDouble(longitude);
                    Log.e("log_tag", "ADDING GEOPOINT" + title);
                    point = new GeoPoint((int) (lat * 1E6),
                            (int) (lng * 1E6));
                    OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(point, title,
                            country);
                    itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayItem);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
            }

            itemizedOverlay.populateNow();

            mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);
            if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                MapController controller = mapView.getController();
                controller.setCenter(point);
                controller.setZoom(7);
            } else {
                // example restoring focused state of overlays
                int focused;
                focused = savedInstanceState.getInt("focused_1", -1);
                if (focused >= 0) {
                    itemizedOverlay.setFocus(itemizedOverlay
                            .getItem(focused));
                }
            }

        }

    }.execute();
}
```

Comment: hardik thanks buddy could you please place them for me using my code,so it would be more easy for me to understand

Comment: You first refer http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/ this. Tell me after if any issue. Its a good example regarding your problem.

Comment: i have used same code to use json parser, but i am struggling to know exactly what code need to move in onPostExecute() method, and where to put onPostExecute() method, please tell me bro

Comment: thanks i have tried, in this line: JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray("maps"); getting problem like earlier, specially in getJSONArray

Comment: declare JSONObject json = null; as global variable.

Comment: Now getting unfortunately app has stopped,and Logcat says:-- 10-27 12:56:07.725: E/AndroidRuntime(721): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-27 12:56:07.725: E/AndroidRuntime(721):  at com.erachnida.restaurant.versionoct.MapView.onCreate(MapView.java:52)

Answer (score 1):

Have you read [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)?

In `Asynctask` `doinBackground()` method executes in separate thread created by Asynctask, which actually is the purpose of making the task Async to reduce the load on `UIThread`

Whereas, `onPostExecute()` method do execute in `UIThread` after the execution of `doInBanckground()`

The changes you need to see after the execution of certain task in `doInBackground` must be written in `onPostExecute` like, for example, if you are doing some webservice action in `doInBackground` you may be using `ProgressDialog` dismissing it is written in `onPostExecute`.

or in your case you have got `json` array dispalying array value must be written inside `onPostExecute`.

**Edited**
try this code, since I am not sure about `mapview` have just tried it..

```
    class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            // Perform a GET request for a JSON list
            HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet("https://dl.***.com/maps.json");
            // Get the response that sends back
            HttpResponse response = null;
            try {
                response = client.execute(request);
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            // Convert this response into a readable string
            String jsonString = null;
            try {
                jsonString = StreamUtils.convertToString(response.getEntity().getContent());
            } catch (IllegalStateException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            // Create a JSON object that we can use from the String
            JSONObject json = null;
            try {
                json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }


            try{
                JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray("maps");
                Log.e("log_tag", "Opening JSON Array ");
                for(int i=0;i < jsonArray.length();i++){                      
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String latitude =  jsonObject.getString("latitude");
                    String longitude =  jsonObject.getString("longitude");
                    String title =  jsonObject.getString("title");
                    String country = jsonObject.getString("country");
                    double lat = Double.parseDouble(latitude);
                    double lng = Double.parseDouble(longitude);
                    Log.e("log_tag", "ADDING GEOPOINT"+title); 
                    point = new GeoPoint((int) (lat * 1E6), (int) (lng * 1E6));
                    OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(point, title, country);
                    itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayItem);
               }
           }catch(JSONException e)        {
               Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
           } 


           return jsonString;
       }

           @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
 itemizedOverlay.populateNow(); 

           mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);
           if (savedInstanceState == null) {
               MapController controller = mapView.getController();
               controller.setCenter(point);
               controller.setZoom(7);
           } else {
               // example restoring focused state of overlays
               int focused;
               focused = savedInstanceState.getInt("focused_1", -1);
               if (focused >= 0) {
                   itemizedOverlay.setFocus(itemizedOverlay.getItem(focused));
               }
           }
              }

    }
```

Comment: please tell me what code exactly i need to place under onPostExecute, the reason i have tried earlier but getting many errors, that's why i also want to know where i am doing silly mistake

Comment: The things which needs to be added to the map fetched from the `json` array need to be inside the `onPostExecute` method.

Comment: bobbe i said i have tried to place but getting problem, so could you please show me by using my code and as you thik onPostExecute() should look like, then i will find out where i am missing or doing wrong,so just need to show those lines by copy and paste using my code

Comment: I hope you have called this Asynctask. like

`new DownloadWebPageTask().execute();` wherever it has to be called

Comment: sorry but i have not i think this is the only reason i am not getting json data into mapview am i right

Comment: i have placed this line below itemizedOverlay.populateNow(); but still not getting, anything wrong

Comment: that has to be written in your `UIThread` in your `onCreate` or wherever you want this to happen

Comment: sorry i forgot to tell u that i have tried it first like here:-mapView.setSatellite(false);
    new DownloadWebPageTask().execute(); in onCreate(), but getting error message :- DownloadWebPageTask cannot be resolved to a type

Answer (score 0):

You Didn't initialize the TapControlledMapView  Object. Initialize it and try.